# when i am trying to install npm it says : 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80] what to do?

Tags: npm, ubuntu-16.04, apt-get

Following comes when i am trying to install npm

> Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl-dev_1.0.2d-0ubuntu1.5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

Answer (score 2):

Please update your package list: `apt-get update`

The current version of `libssl-dev` is 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.11 (See [Ubuntu Packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial-updates&searchon=names&keywords=libssl-dev)).

Old versions of packages will be deleted from the ubuntu repository once they are out-of-date long enough. After pulling the new package info, the package manager will install the new version.

Answer (score 0):

I used to get this error as well.

```
$ sudo apt install python3-pip
...
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_5.15.0-88.98_amd64.deb  
404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
```

If I tried to update apt, I would get an error like this:

```
$ sudo apt update
...
E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates
/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 19min 41s). Updates for 
this repository will not be applied.
```

In my case, the issue was that the WSL2 Ubuntu and Windows system clocks were not in sync.

```
$ timedatectl
               Local time: Wed 2023-11-29 12:14:28 EST
           Universal time: Wed 2023-11-29 17:14:28 UTC
                 RTC time: Wed 2023-11-29 19:15:21
                Time zone: America/New_York (EST, -0500)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

After resynchronizing the clocks, I could complete updating apt and installing packages.

```
$ sudo hwclock -s
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install python3-pip
```